# PowerShell & SQL Server : Attempt to retrieve data for object failed for ManagedComputer

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm currently writing a script to install a new SQL Server instance with PowerShell.
In this script, after the instance has been created, I disable the dynamic port and give it a new fixed port.

```
Import-Module SqlPs

[...] # Install a new instance SQL Server

$wmi = (Get-Item "SQLServer:\SQL\$Env:ComputerName").ManagedComputer
$urn = "ManagedComputer[@Name='$Env:ComputerName']/ ServerInstance[@Name='$Instance']/ ServerProtocol[@Name='Tcp']"
$tcp = $wmi.GetSmoObject($urn)
$tcp.IPAddresses['IPAll'].IPAddressProperties['TcpPort'].Value         = "$Port"
$tcp.IPAddresses['IPAll'].IPAddressProperties['TcpDynamicPorts'].Value = ""
$tcp.Alter()
```

This script works correctly but when I try to run it a second times on the same PowerShell window, it return the following error :

```
Exception calling "GetSmoObject" with "1" argument(s): "Attempt to retrieve data for object failed for ManagedComputer 'MYSERVER'."
At .\New-Instance.ps1:316 char:5
+     $tcp = $wmi.GetSmoObject($urn)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedOperationException

$Error[0] | Format-List -Force
Exception             : System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "GetSmoObject" with "1" argument(s): "Attempt to retrieve data for object failed for ManagedComputer 'MYSERVER'." --->
                        Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: Attempt to retrieve data for object failed for ManagedComputer 'MYSERVER'. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.MissingObjectException: The
                        ServerInstance 'MYINSTANCE' does not exist on the server.
                           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer.GetSmoObjectRec(Urn urn)
                           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer.GetSmoObjectRec(Urn urn)
                           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer.GetSmoObject(Urn urn)
                           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer.GetSmoObject(Urn urn)
                           at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object )
                           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                           at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
TargetObject          :
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedOperationException
ErrorDetails          :
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, D:\SqlServer\Scripts\New-Instance.ps1: line 316
                        at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
PSMessageDetails      :
```

Yet, the instance 'MYINSTANCE' has been installed successfully. I think the recovered ManagedComputer hasn't been update and doesn't include the new instance 'MYINSTANCE'.

How can I force the refresh of the recovered ManagedComputer ?

My PowerShell Version :

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  3471
```

Comment: I think you may need to exit and re-launch the PowerShell ISE in order to reload the app domain. Consider running the script from a command prompt instead (e.g.  `powershell -File ".\YourScript.ps1"`) so each script instance is a separate PS session.

Comment: Re-launch PoweerShell is also the only "solution" I found for the moment.
Running the script from the command prompt works every time but I prefer a solution users can launch from PowerShell directly. This will serve as a temporary solution for the moment.Thanks for your suggestion.